# prettier configuration error, prettier not working

Tags: prettier, prettier-eslint

I got an error in prettier. how to solve [this issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gTMp9.png)?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like, for whatever reason, there is no configuration file for prettier in the place it is looking for it, namely your root folder.

I would check if a `~\.prettierrc.js` file exists, by typing `cd ~\ && dir /ah` and see if `.pretterrc.js` shows up. If not, create that file and copy this:

```
module.exports = {
  trailingComma: "es5",
  tabWidth: 4,
  semi: false,
  singleQuote: true,
};
```

which is just the default configuration found here: https://prettier.io/docs/en/configuration.html