# Why prettier is not working on my ubuntu based vs code

Tags: javascript, ubuntu, visual-studio-code, prettier

I installed vs code on ubuntu but is not working. Anytime I tried to use it as the default  format I get error **( Prettier  configuration fail )** but meanwhile, I did all necessary configuration.

Comment: Can you add the full stacktrace? Have you checked this thread? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64970988/prettier-configuration-error-prettier-not-working

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.